# Why is the pinescript not plotting lines on chart accurately?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4

The basic function of the script is to draw lines on wick on liquidity wicks(previos wicks that were not swept).
The script is;

```
//@version=5
indicator("Liquidity Profiling", overlay = true, max_bars_back = 4999)
highs = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, timeframe.period, high)

prevH = 0.0
currH = nz(highs[0])

if barstate.islast
    for i=0 to 4998
        if currH >= prevH
            line.new(bar_index-i, high[i], bar_index+1, high[i], extend = extend.right, color=color.white, width = 1)
            prevH := currH
        
        currH := nz(highs[i+1])
```

It is generating the chart as follows leaving the candles in red squared highlighted area where it should generate the lines too as per logic of the code.
[image: script chart image showing lines on liquidity area but no lines on first few candles]

But if I change the for loop from

```
for i=0 to 4998
```

to

```
for i=0 to 300
```

then it will generate the liquidity lines on first 300 candles wicks and of course the later wicks won't be covered as the loop now runs for first 300 candles, but in case of first 4998 candles why does it not generate the wicks for first 300(of a bit lesser than 300) wicks?
[image: after changing loop to run for just first 300 candles the lines are generated perfectly as they should]

Answer (score 0):

Just change the line

```
indicator("Liquidity Profiling", overlay = true, max_bars_back = 4999)
```

to

```
indicator("Liquidity Profiling", overlay = true, max_bars_back = 4999, max_lines_count = 500)
```

This will allow more lines to be drawn on the chart.